# Robot model orientation is improper with respect to map frame

Tags: navigation, fixed-frame, base-odometry, amcl, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Robot model is not properly oriented (upside down) in rviz when "map" is selected as fixed frame. When the fixed frame is odom the robot model was perfectly aligned and oriented in rviz. How to bring the robot to same position as it was in odom frame.

Refer the result below
[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225379/robot-model-orientation-is-improper-with-respect-to-map-frame./) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2016-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The co-ordinate system used is wrong, solution for [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/224754/error-while-building-map-in-slam_gmapping/) question solved the issue.

---

Originally posted by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) with karma: 173 on 2016-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0